# What is this tree with pointed bumps on its bark?

Tags: identification, trees

This tree was found on a nature path in the Fort Myers area in Florida. The leaves are compound, most are 5 compound but some are 7.  They are similar to a buckeye tree.

This is a picture of the tree's bark.

[image]

Comment: are the dead branches we see in the background part of the tree?

Comment: No - The tree partially fell.  The leaves are compound, most are 5 compound but some are 7.  They are similar to a buckeye tree.

Comment: Are there bulges in the trunk?

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be the *Ceiba speciosa* or *Chrorisia speciosa*. It's commonly called the silk floss tree and is a species found in Florida. The one you're looking at has bunches of conical "spikes" and appears to be quite aged or possibly diseased. Not easy to tell from a single photo.

You can read about them [here](http://lee.ifas.ufl.edu/Hort/GardenPubsAZ/BombaxCeibaRedSilkCottonTree.pdf), from the University of Florida. Notice the middle photo on page 2. Also, the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiba_speciosa) article. We had one at my college and it's quite messy when the pods open. And the [leaves](http://www.plantconservatory.calpoly.edu/Tree/images/ceiba_leaves_s.jpg) from a Southern California variety.